# n-m and @version

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, caching

Caching a n-m relation between `article` and `tag`, this is my DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE TAG_ARTICLE (
  articles_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
  tags_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT "TAG_ARTICLE_pkey" PRIMARY KEY(articles_id, tags_id),
  CONSTRAINT fk6xn1snukol646eslcghksu1s9 FOREIGN KEY (articles_id)
    REFERENCES public.TAG (id)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION
    NOT DEFERRABLE,
  CONSTRAINT fkrecpkpqx4li97ri4xl0e1j9rf FOREIGN KEY (tags_id)
    REFERENCES public.ARTICLE(id)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION
    NOT DEFERRABLE
) 
WITH (oids = false);
```

This is my m-part in `Article`:

```
/**
 * The m-part of the n-m relation. The non-owning-side.
 */
@Deprecated
@ManyToMany(mappedBy="articles")
public Set<Tag> getTags() {
    return tags;
}
```

And this is my N-side in `Tag`:

```
/**
 * The n-part of the n-m relation. The owning-side.
 */
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name=Article, joinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name=ARTICLES_FK, referencedColumnName = ID_FIELD_NAME, nullable = false)
}, inverseJoinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name=Article.TAGS_FK, referencedColumnName = Article.ID_FIELD_NAME, nullable = false)
})
public Set<Article> getArticles() {
    return articles;
}
```

Works great. I have many entries in both tables and I introduce the `@Version` field to check if i have to clear my internal cache like this

```
SELECT max(version) FROM TAG;
SELECT max(version) FROM ARTICLE;
```

Unfortunately `TAG_ARTICLE` does not have a `version`-column but I need to clear the cache if a member is not part of a team anymore.

What is a good solution?

Comment: You shouldn't do caching like that, Hibernate has other means to automatically invalidate a cache when you update data. Apart from that, the version of the tag should be updated when you remove the article since it is the "owner" of the relation

Comment: @ChristianBeikov To update the owner (version only, even if nothing changed) sounds not like an good solution because if another application having the oppposide way: the non-owning side as owning-side will not be able to trust the version field because the non-owning-side may be more new. But I see that you understand the problem, even if the description is complex.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "non-owning-side may be more new". After all, you should give a little more detail on how you do your cache invalidation. Do you check versions regularly i.e. every minute? Are there other applications that might update data?